# Media queries in html email templates

Tags: html, css, email

Using

```
<style>...</style>
```

and classes in email html are not allowed, but responsive emails are required. Can somebody say alternatives to the next code

```
 <style>
    @media (max-width:570px) {

      .row-content {
        width: 100% !important;
      }
    }
 <style>
```

? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media queries in general have [pretty good support across email clients](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-at-media/). There are a few limitations (like Gmail not understand `height` based media queries), but this is usually not a problem. There are however a few edge cases worth knowing about:

- Gmail on mobile (iOS and Android) does not support `<style>` tags (and thus media queries) when using a Non Gmail Account (like an Outlook.com email address for example).
- Yahoo on Android requires an empty `<head></head>` tag before your real head tag as it removes the first `<head>` (and all its content) it finds.

For these cases, the best practice is usually to opt for a different coding approach, not relying on media queries like the fluid/hybrid technique or a mobile first approach.

Comment: Emty "<head></head>"?

Comment: Yep. You can read more about this here: https://github.com/hteumeuleu/email-bugs/issues/28